# How to discard errors of PowerShell ActiveDirectory cmdlets?

Tags: powershell, scripting

I am writing a PowerShell script (in a PowerShell 5.1 environnement) and I need to list all users from groups set in a folder's permissions. But some groups are not relevant so when I try to *Get-ADGroupMember* on it, I've got an expected error.

To discard this error, I tried the following :

```bsh
Get-ADGroupMember Fake_Group -Server ad.example.com 2>&1 $null
Get-ADGroupMember Fake_Group -Server ad.example.com 2>&1 | Out-Null
```

But in both cases, the result is the same : error is displayed.

```
get-aduser : Cannot find an object with identity: 'Fake_Group' under 'DC=example.com'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-ADGroupMember Fake_Group -Server ad.example.com 2>&1 | ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Fake_Group:ADGroup) [Get-ADGroupMember], ADIdentityNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADIdentityNotFoundException,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADGroupMember
```

So my question is : why is this error still displayed ?

And then, how could I discard this error or is there a better way to list users from groups set in a folder's permissions than just try to *Get-ADGroupMember* on the whole result of *Get-Acl* even on no relevant object ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because Out-Null does nothing in this regard, you would need to use try/catch statements and might even need to add -ErrorAction Stop as not all errors in AD commands are terminating errors:

```
Try{
    Get-ADGroupMember $GROUPNAME -Server $SEVRER -ErrorAction Stop
    #The group is found, do whatever you want here
}Catch{
    Write-Host "Some error occured"
}
```

Comment: I've just tried this solution with *Start-Transcript* and, if in a console indeed the error is hidden by a *try..catch*, it is not when transcipting :/

Comment: 3 questions: Why use a transcript when you can just add a line each time the group is found? What errors are you getting in the transcript? Why unmark my answer when it still answers your original question?

Comment: 1) As I said, I'm writing a script so I do some other stuff and not only Get-ADGroupMember. The goal is to write a report based on the output of this script. 2) I've got "TerminatingError(Get-ADGroupMember): Cannot find an object with identity ..." 3) It was a missclick sorry, indeed it answers the original question

Comment: Looking back in memory and backed up using the source below, it looked like this is by design. The only other way is to use your own logging. Transcripts capture EVERYTHING which is why they so handy whilst debugging. Link here:https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2137491-when-using-try-catch-terminating-error-appearing-in-transcript-log

Comment: Oh I see.. so how is it possible to redirect stdout and stderr for each command to a file like { some commands } > file 2>&1 in Bash ? I've found Start-Transcript when I looked for and that's why I use it in fact, to answer your fisrt question.

Comment: Pretty much the same way, take a look at this (Most information can be found just by a single Google search): https://www.koskila.net/how-to-redirect-console-output-to-a-file/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194381/discussion-between-purerstamp-and-i-t-delinquent).